# Dynamically resize text using rectagle in asp.net client-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, resize, client-side

I want to create a web-service that can combine user input text to image .
Let's say , I have textbox to input user's text string , and image preview which display preview of combination of user's text and user's uploaded image .  Referencing this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7462/Dynamically-Write-Text-On-An-Image) link , I'm ok with this step .

But I want to enable user to resize the text on preview , using rectangle box around text like this [image]

How can I approach to make this ?  Any third-party tool for this ?
Jquery or whatever !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by using [jQuery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/). It enable any DOM element to be resizable by dragging the cursor grab at the right or bottom border to the desired width or height.

I've put up a simple `jsFiddle` demo for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/hmJCQ/

---

**Update** — *as per OP's question in comment, for using `jQuery UI Resizable` with `jQuery UI Draggable`*

Updated `jsFiddle` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hmJCQ/1/

Comment: wow , that link is cool , can I use both of `resizable`(http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) and `Draggable` (http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) in one `div` ?